# How to use ngSwitch in loops

Tags: angular

How do I set the index of the square dots and use `ngSwitch` to connect `.form-style` div with my list of questions and inputs. The idea is to hide and show each of questions by switching around with the square dots. However it show only one question on the page.

```
<!--contact.component.html-->
<app-contact-modal [modalTitle] = "'Some Title'"
                   [blocking] = 'false'
                   [modalId] = 'modalId' >
  <div class="form_container">
    <div class="square_dot-row">
      <div class="square_dot" [active]="isSelected(1)" (click)="setSquare(1)"
        *ngFor="let square_dot of square_dots"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_box">
      <form class="form-style">
        <h1>How can we help? Tell us about your challenges.</h1>
        <textarea class="lightbox_form" col="1000"></textarea>
      </form>
      <form class="form-style">
        <h1>What services are you interested in</h1>
        <ul class="form-items_row">
        <li class="form-items">Social Media</li>
        <li class="form-items">Video / Studio</li>
        <li class="form-items">Web / Digital</li>
        <li class="form-items">Creative Design</li>
        <li class="form-items">Design</li>
        <li class="form-items">Media</li>
        </ul>
      </form>
      <form class="form-style">
        <h1>What is your goal? What are you trying to accomplish?</h1>
        <textarea class="lightbox_form" col="1000"></textarea>
      </form>
      <form class="form-style">
        <h1>Company</h1>
        <input type="text" size="77" id="form-input">
      </form>
      <form class="form-style">
        <h1>Name</h1>
        <input type="text" size="77" id="form-input">
      </form>
      <form class="form-style">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <input type="text" size="77" id="form-input">
      </form>
      <form class="form-style">
        <h1>Email</h1>
        <input type="text" size="77" id="form-input">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</app-contact-modal>
```

contact.component.ts

```
    import { Component, HostBinding, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { routeFadeStateTrigger } from '../shared/route-animations';
import { contactSlideTrigger } from './contact-animations';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CMSService } from '../../services/cms.service';
import { CMSProvider } from '../../providers/cms';
import { ModalService } from '../../services/modal.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css'],
  providers: [ModalService],
  animations: [
    routeFadeStateTrigger,
    contactSlideTrigger
  ]
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {
  square_dots = ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''];
  square_btn = 0;
  showModal = false;
  @HostBinding('@routeFadeState') routeAnimation = true;
  footerObject = '';

  setSquare(num: number) {
    this.square_btn = num;
  }

  isSelected(num: number) {
    return this.square_btn === num;
  }

  constructor(private router:Router,private cmsService: CMSService, public modalService: ModalService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cmsService.getCMS(9225, (data) => {
       console.log(data);
       this.initMap(data);
    });
   }

   initMap(data: any) {
    this.footerObject = data.footer[0];
    console.log(this.footerObject);
  }

  getRoute() {
    if(this.router.url === '/contact') {
      return 'sticky-footer';
    }
  }

  delElem() {
    if(this.router.url !== '/contact') {
      return 'remove-el';
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: By creating a minimal example you increase your chances a lot to get a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[ngSwitch]="expression"` and `*ngSwitchCase="value"`:

```
<!--contact.component.html-->
<app-contact-modal [modalTitle] = "'Some Title'"
                   [blocking] = 'false'
                   [modalId] = 'modalId' >
  <div class="form_container">
    <div class="square_dot-row">
      <div class="square_dot" [active]="isSelected(1)" (click)="setSquare(1)"
        *ngFor="let square_dot of square_dots"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_box" [ngSwitch]="square_dot">
      <form class="form-style" *ngSwitchCase="1">
        <h1>How can we help? Tell us about your challenges.</h1>
        <textarea class="lightbox_form" col="1000"></textarea>
      </form>
      <form class="form-style" *ngSwitchCase="2">
        <h1>What services are you interested in</h1>
        <ul class="form-items_row">
        <li class="form-items">Social Media</li>
        <li class="form-items">Video / Studio</li>
        <li class="form-items">Web / Digital</li>
        <li class="form-items">Creative Design</li>
        <li class="form-items">Design</li>
        <li class="form-items">Media</li>
        </ul>
      </form>
      <form class="form-style" *ngSwitchCase="3">
        <h1>What is your goal? What are you trying to accomplish?</h1>
        <textarea class="lightbox_form" col="1000"></textarea>
      </form>
      <form class="form-style" *ngSwitchCase="4">
        <h1>Company</h1>
        <input type="text" size="77" id="form-input">
      </form>
      <form class="form-style" *ngSwitchCase="5">
        <h1>Name</h1>
        <input type="text" size="77" id="form-input">
      </form>
      <form class="form-style" *ngSwitchCase="6">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <input type="text" size="77" id="form-input">
      </form>
      <form class="form-style" *ngSwitchCase="7">
        <h1>Email</h1>
        <input type="text" size="77" id="form-input">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</app-contact-modal>
```